# Decode Multi-Layer HEVC

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc, rtsp

I'm trying to decode an HEVC/H.265+ rtsp stream to an image using ffmpeg as follows:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -stimeout 10000000 -i 'rtsp://user:passwd@url:port/Streaming/tracks/101?starttime=20210826T130000Z&endtime=20210826T130010Z' -vframes 1 -y image.jpg
```

but I'm getting the following:

```
[rtsp @ 0x56031fe7f500] Multi-layer HEVC coding is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.

[rtsp @ 0x56031fe7f500] Multi-layer HEVC coding is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.

[rtsp @ 0x56031fe7f500] Multi-layer HEVC coding is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.

[rtsp @ 0x56031fe7f500] Multi-layer HEVC coding is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.

[rtsp @ 0x56031fe7f500] Multi-layer HEVC coding is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
```

I tried using the latest version of ffmpeg but still the same issue.

Comment: If you are indeed using the latest version from git as mentioned in the error message then  you have to conclude that "your file has a feature which has not been implemented". Not really a Ubuntu question.

Comment: Ok, I will move this to https://video.stackexchange.com/